# Notify us when an answer we've accepted has been edited

Tags: feature-request, edits, accepted-answer, notifications

This could potentially completely change the answer. We should be given the opportunity to review it and if necessary comment or change our minds about accepting it. Of course we can do that now but there are no edit notifications so we either have to review all our accepted answers periodically or get lucky and find it.

Comment: How about a notification of an edit to *any* post you've voted on? Since you can only change an old vote if the post has been recently edited, it would be nice to have some notification of an edit.

Comment: Thas not a bad idea but I guess the concern is the noise factor. Lots of people have voted on thousands of posts. One has to wonder at how many notifications this will result in. It might be fine. Who knows? It's definitely a concern though.

Comment: Question: does voting this question up count as support for the idea?  I think it's a good idea, but an up-vote merely indicates that I think this is something good to discuss, no?

Comment: As a feature request, I personally consider an upvote for the question support for the idea. If it were a discussion I'd consider it an indication that the topic was worth discussing.

Comment: Add a change threshold an I'm sold.

Comment: A change threshold seems like it'd be hard to properly implement.  No more than x characters changed?  What if the change was just from "yes" to "no"?  That's only 3 characters different (depending on how you count it), but that is a much bigger change than from "Yes, with one exception" "Yes, with one exception and that exception is _____"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I recently had this exact situation happen in reverse. I answered a question, which was then substantially edited. My answer was subsequently down voted because it was a poor answer to the edited (and completely different!) question.

This is pretty harsh, since I don't see that I did anything wrong, but I can see why a viewer faced with the current question would come to the negative decision.

I think some way of linking specific versions of answers to versions of questions would be helpful, or at least some sort of visual cue indicating the edits have taken place.

Comment: Such a feature has been suggested in another post: [Notify us when the question has been edited after posting an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2322/notify-us-when-the-question-has-been-edited-after-posting-an-answer)

Comment: It's not "harsh", because it's not personal. The effect on your rep is secondary (though, yes, a shame); the important thing is that the answer, through downvoting, was marked as not being a useful answer to the question. Even though the question had changed, that property ended up being an accurate representation of the state of affairs. It's right! It would have been useful though had you been notified so that you could delete the answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a really good idea. I forget, are edits to your question/answers notified? Because, if they aren't, they should be as well for much the same reason.

Comment: On your summary page for the period selected it says "N Edits to your Posts". You really have to be looking for it to find it.

Answer (score 1):

It's a good idea, but I'd add a few things:

- Notify on changes on **every** question/answer you have voted upon,
- but **only** if the change was over 50% of the state when you voted/accepted the question/answer.

May be it would still mean a lot of noise, but if this is implemented, even if it's only for accepted answers, the second point should be added (with maybe a lower threshold).

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't the "Recent Activity" already do this? I believe that it shows any posts (answers or questions) that have been edited on any of your questions or your answer.

It's maybe not an in your face notification, but I kinda like it better.

But I could be wrong.

Comment: You have the concepts reversed.  You are not notified when someone edits an accepted answer unless you are the person who wrote the answer.  If you accept an answer someone else has written, then they edit their answer, you do not receive a notification because it is not "your" answer.