# Notify us when one of our posts is edited

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, edits, notifications, global-inbox

Your summary page shows "N Edits to your posts" for the selected time period but you really have to be looking for it.

Could we add edits to the notification feed? You could put the reason for the edit (entered--or not--when the editor changes it) and just a link to the post.

Comment: Also linked to this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2303/notify-us-when-an-answer-weve-accepted-has-been-edited (Yes it is shown on the related but needs more attention too, I guess)

Comment: So, is this being taken care of? I would really appreciate something like this.

Comment: Cletus, this is implemented, so you should accept [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2305/notify-us-when-one-of-our-posts-is-edited/135961#135961) (also @RileyE)

Comment: @TobiasKienzler Thanks Tobias. Is there a feature request for notifications upon our question's answers or our answer's question being edited? I know that can change how we accept, upvote, downvote and answer on SO, so I think its a valid request, right? I've been downvoted because I answered a question that was edited and my answer was incorrect for the current state of the question.

Comment: @RileyE I once requested [Notify question OP (and those who marked it a favourite) if an answer has been modified](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64692/146482) (no success so far) and here's the other way around: [Notify us when the question has been edited after posting an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2322/146482)

Comment: @TobiasKienzler Oh. That should also probably extend to notifying the people who favorited if an answer is selected. Or maybe an answer subscription option for a certain question? But thank you so much!

Answer (score 34):

I agree - this feature can be useful as a way to teach new users how to improve their questions, especially if a description of what was edited will be available as well.

Comment: +1 for *this feature can be useful as a way to teach new users how to improve their questions*

Answer (score 28):

With the new notifications section in the global inbox, this is now done for [**substantive**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/202359/no-notification-was-received-for-an-edit-to-a-post/202415#202415) edits to your post and for any pending suggested edits to your post.

**When an edit is made to your post:**

[image: Your post was edited.]

**When the edit applies to code:**

[image: Code in your post was edited.]

**When an edit is suggested on your post:**

[image: An edit was suggested to your post, please review it.]

Comment: (Now expecting the notification *An image was added to your post!* `;-)`)

Comment: This is great, thanks for the update! What was that last SE notification for?

Comment: @Shog or animuson - can you perform your dev-foo magic and make this answer accepted so it's on top?

Comment: Naw, but I'll upvote it @Shadow.

Answer (score 20):

Now that we have the global inbox, these notifications should be shown there.

The message could be something like:

> edit on  **Why do java arrays have no indexOf method?**
>   Added: return NOT_FOUND;

I.e. first the question title, then the edit comment. The link could either go to the [revision list](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/6931749/revisions) or the [question/answer itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6931461/why-do-java-arrays-have-no-indexof-method/6931749#6931749).

The inbox could also include suggested edits on my posts by people who don't yet have enough reputation, so I could approve/reject them myself, without needed intervention of other edit-approvers. (They would still be visible on the global queue, of course.)

Comment: YES.  I really hope this gets implemented.  I want to know right away if someone edits my answer.

Comment: @adam don't support for the reasons in my answer

Answer (score 17):

I don't support this:

- I think it will lead to a lot of edit wars. *You, sir, had the audacity to edit my post?* In reality you should not *care* if others edit your posts, since you trust the global community as a caretaker of your content -- right? I'm thinking of the wikipedia folks who monitor every tiny change to a page and have a hair trigger revert finger.. it's happened to me many times there.
- I can tell you that virtually none of the edits I see are "inbox worthy" on metas, so right off the bat I wouldn't want meta edit notifications, which to me is a symptom of not needing them altogether.
- Every new notification we add to the global inbox adds to the "crying wolf" factor of the global inbox and devalues other future messages.
- I really only want things directed TO me in the global inbox, not random things that happened to my posts that I might or (most likely) might not care about.

There is also a trivial workaround: **you can periodically check your profile to see what edits have occurred on your posts, and take action as you see fit.**

Additionally, there *is* a topbar notification for edits as well.

> You have {n} new edits. See your responses.

See it here for me:

[image: You have {n} new edits. See your responses.]

Comment: The prospect of such a feature generating edit wars definitely gives me pause, I'd have to say.

Comment: Actually, I really care about edits on my posts, especially since they are such rare (19 edits in my whole SO history, with 1075 answers and 9 questions. It looks like edits on meta are much more often ... or simply edits on questions are much more often than on answers). And your workaround only works for individual sites, not network wide (or I missed the "responses" tab on [my SE profile](http://stackexchange.com/users/295869)).

Comment: Jeff you're actively overblowing a point of your own by conflating goals. You don't want notifications on any child meta, because only mods or you can do that. If a mod edited your post, it should REALLY be a good edit. Don't lump [metase] in with [child-meta], because they aren't the same, and we know it. I feel the need to edit your post to remove that, just because I can. However, it detracts from your point, so it's a toss-up.

Comment: @jcole what? Any user with 2k rep on the parent site can edit other people's posts on any child meta any time they want. No idea what you're talking about.

Comment: oO seriously? I've been told time and again no editing. FFS. Also, I need to push one of my accounts non-trilogy up over 2k...

Comment: @jcole I think you are thinking of suggested edits, which indeed isn't enabled on metas. But 2k users can edit anywhere, as per usual

Comment: @JeffAtwood I think you're correct sir.

Comment: Does the topbar edit notification only appear when you've been inactive for a certain period? I just stumbled upon a [completely idiotic](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/299702/revisions) edit to one of my posts that I don't remember being informed about. I see now that it's in my responses tab, but thanks to the global inbox, I never think of looking there anymore.

Comment: I care about edits to my posts.  I don't edit-war; most of the time I'd just like to see what happened.  In the unlikely event that someone misunderstands what I said badly enough to edit my code into broken and/or dangerous (with my name still on it) I will of course want to do something about that.  Currently I use my WebCheck program to check all my answers, but I'm running into problems with StackExchange servers telling me I'm sending them too many requests.  It would be nice to have some reassurance that I will be notified, so my script doesn't have to routinely fetch 130+ pages for this

Answer (score 15):

I agree this should be implemented, even our top users only get 10 or so a month.

https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet?tab=responses

I think every one of those edits are inbox worthy. Let Jon decide if they make sense.

I have this on the Trello board, will discuss with the team.

Comment: it's trivial for users who care about edits to check their responses tab for edits every week or so.. why would we want to "cry wolf" and nag them every single time this happens *at the time it happens?* That would also devalue global inbox substantially with naggy messages that aren't even *replies specifically directed at them*.

Comment: at 20k reputation you would be looking at a whooping 2 notifications per month, I would not call that "crying wolf" the best time to teach people is close to the time the action happened.

Comment: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2004/10/just-say-no.html "Innovation is not about saying yes to everything. It's about saying NO to all but the most crucial features." Sure, add this notification to global inbox.. what's the harm.. then another.. then another.. what's the harm? Without discipline and rigor, pretty soon the inbox becomes just another eminently ignorable source of noise. Inbox is supposed to be only for the absolutely most important things, things directly specifically at you that *need* your response.

Comment: *however* if you want to **add another "subtab" to inbox for low-pri stuff like edits** I possibly could support that. But it *absolutely cannot* increment the big red IMPORTANT counter.

Comment: @JeffAtwood we have a general serious issue around notifications I feel needs to be addressed, there are just too many incoming buckets. We have notifications in the inbox. We have big notifications in the header of the page, that only go away when you click x or the link. We have notification numbers on the user profile in 4 tabs. Too many buckets to check and deal with. Too many buckets.

Comment: @JeffAtwood actually I am fine with that ... I feel having "low pri" info in the inbox would allow us to get rid of a few buckets ... want to find stuff out .. go to inbox.

Comment: well, the wrong solution is to start spamming our users with tons of meaningless alerts in the one really great notification system we have. It is great *precisely because* it is so disciplined and does not waste my time with irrelevant stuff. And for the record, I still don't think edit notifications are very important at all, there are at least 5 or 6 other things I would put in front of them like bounty notifies, accepted answer changes, etc.

Comment: @JeffAtwood except that we do waste your time, in 2/3 different ways depending on which bucket the notification reaches. I am the last person to advocate spamming users with crap.

Comment: @waffles Looks like the link to the responses tab is only visible for Jon and moderators, not for me.

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann replace the `/22656/jon-skeet` with your own information. They used it for example because everyone knows Skeet. Additionally, very few people but Skeet have the skill, knowledge or audacity to edit most of his posts.

Comment: @waffles I'm all about having a single bucket of low-importance that aggregates all my site-updates so that I don't have to click the X or visit and look at a sub-tab.