# What actions to take against wrong edits other than rollback and why isn't there a notification?

Tags: support, edits

Here is a case: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4760279/300011

This answer was edited by a user and the example given in the answer stopped working (he/she didn't even test it). It somehow got approved too (No idea how). What to do? (I already rolled back but is there anything else that needs to be done?)

The other thing is why wasn't there a notification for me that my answer was edited? Is this normal or must I have missed it? (Saw by chance).

Comment: I would not have ever approved such an edit myself, because it was clearly intended to *change* your answer. Rolling it back was the correct thing to do. If it gets invalidly edited again, you should flag it for moderator attention.

Comment: Flag for moderator attention. Note that you can simply roll back an edit. If you feel you must editorialize, do so in the comments, not in the answer.  Are you sure the edit was incorrect?  The suggested editor gave an explanation of their edit, and two other people agreed with it.

Comment: I also hesitated before doing it but I proceeded anyway as there could be some users who had the wrong code and I felt the responsibility to warn them (Yes maybe I should change the tone there... What do you think?)

Comment: Yes I am sure the edit was incorrect as the example stopped working. You can try it in your browsers console.

Comment: You can leave a comment with a [link to the suggested edit](http://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/179897), explaining why it was incorrect.

Comment: I'll go on and do that. Thank you.

Comment: See here for the edit notifications feature request: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2305/notify-us-when-one-of-our-posts-is-edited

Comment: Upvoted that. Thanks again for the help. Could you please gather the information you have given here in comments, as an answer to this question so that I can accept it? Is it too much to ask? =)

Comment: @PeeHah can have the EXP.

Comment: @EgeÖzcan - don't sweat it - stuff like this seldom slips through the cracks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct thing to do is just to rollback the answer if you don't agree.

You could also add a comment and @user to ask the user about whether he thought that solutions was better.

As stated in the comments by [Robert Harvey♦](/users/102937/robert-harvey):

> Flag for moderator attention. Note that you can simply roll back an edit. If you feel you must editorialize, do so in the comments, not in the answer. Are you sure the edit was incorrect? The suggested editor gave an explanation of their edit, and two other people agreed with it.

Also check out: [Notify us when one of our posts is edited](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2305/notify-us-when-one-of-our-posts-is-edited) for more information about the feature request of a notifications system on changes.

Comment: as stated about 4 times in the comments.

Comment: @Gabe yup I started this answer some minutes ago and got called away by my boss so I just submitted. Is this bad?

Comment: Its not bad... a mod might convert it into a comment or something.

Comment: @Gabe Why would a mod do that? It is an answer.

Comment: I'm accepting this as an answer but it needs to be stated that comments to the question are more explanatory than the answer itself =)

Comment: @PeeHaa Notice how I mentioned 'or something' I've seen answers get converted into comments before, I'm unsure of how they handle it.

Comment: @PeeHaa Because mods are a) human b) like comments c) don't like comments d) some of the above e) none of the above

Comment: @casperOne I know this one! Here it goes: It depends :-)