# Disputing edits made to new post

Tags: support, review, edits

I recently posted my first question on Stack Overflow, but I ask/answer quite a bit on other Stack Exchange sites. As it was my first post, it was reviewed and edited, but I disagree with the edits made. They don't really change the question itself, nor impact any potential answer, but they make it *less* correct, not more.

I thought about just editing it back, but I don't want that to come off wrong. I feel like I need some kind of explanation for disputing the edits (as I have done below), but I don't know of anywhere to do that on the post. Should I just change it back? Should I contact a moderator? Is my English Nerd side just acting up again?

"...the project consists of **syntax** that I cannot seem to find..." => "...the project consists of **the syntax** that I cannot seem to find..." *(this is arbitrary at best, but from an English standpoint, it makes no sense. The original is perfectly valid (since the plural of 'syntax' is 'syntax') and says what I intended. The edit suggests that there is a single syntax I cannot find, which it incorrect)*

"Begin **VB.Form** [FormName]" => "Begin **VB. Form** [FormName]" *(not even sure where this came from. VB.Form is the object name, not a sentence delimiter)*

"...as I would expect **coming** from C#" => "...as I would expect **to come** from C#" *(I was referring to my experience moving from C# to VB. It's not that big of a deal, but this changes the meaning entirely. Perhaps the correct edit would be "...as I would **expect,** coming from C#)*

Comment: Doubt there is much more to do beyond what's already suggested [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119364/what-actions-to-take-against-wrong-edits-other-than-rollback-and-why-isnt-there). TL;DR: rollback, comment, ask editor for reason via comment reply, or flag in case it escalates. (e.g. becoming an edit war).

Comment: Yes, if you disagree with an edit, rollback. In the edit history you find that option.

Comment: Also, in your specific case the actual problem is robo reviewers who approve any edit without bothering to check it first. It's a major problem which made me give up on suggested edits review on SO. The new user who made wrong edit is not to blame, they don't know how SO works and likely not familiar with VB at all, judging by the wrong code edit. It's the high rep users' responsibility to review and reject such edits.

Comment: If I had reviewed that suggested edit I just denied it for being too minor. No need to waste reviewers time with such little changes.

Comment: @ShadowKeepsSocialDistance Thanks for the info and for taking care of the rollback for me! I'll keep that in mind for the future.

Answer (score 14):

As much as I’d sometimes like to school editors, I’ve found that it’s not really worthwhile as your places for explaining stuff like this are extremely limited and it’s unlikely that the editor would come back to see the change if they’re not alerted to it.

I mean, you *can* leave a comment to alert them (@name the editor manually), I just don’t tend to do this when it’s just one slightly bad edit.

(Flagging for a moderator is overkill and should only be done if it’s a series of bad edits that have continued after the user was talked to or something else that you can’t handle yourself.)

Just reject the edit ([if possible](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/295028/323179)) or else rollback. (You can add an [edit summary when you rollback](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/41953/323179) too.) On the slim chance that the editor cares about this, they can leave *you* a comment asking for clarification.

Besides, you own the post and what you’re changing back isn’t unreasonable.

Answer (score 8):

Having a look at the [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61893042/revisions) of the question you reference, it seems an edit was suggested by a user and was [later reviewed](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/26170559) by a >2k user, who has full edit privileges. The reviewer used the **Improve Edit** review choice to edit away the VBA tag, which makes sense as that question was not about VBA.

The crux of the issue was the reviewer choosing **Improve Edit** instead of **Reject and Edit**. This action kept the previous changes and allowed the reviewer to apply their own. The changes made by the suggested edit were pretty superfluous, as you point out, but I imagine that the reviewer simply wanted to edit that tag away and chose the first option that would let him do so without really reviewing the currently proposed changes. I prefer to consider this an *accident* rather than an *oversight*, as I'm sure the reviewer had no intention of negatively impacting your post, but the prevalence of robo-reviewers ([mentioned by Shadow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/348174/disputing-edits-made-to-new-post/348176#comment1164941_348174)) is still a problem.

The best choice would be to rollback the edits (and hopefully preserve the tag edit mentioned previously) and leave it at that. If the former editor were to suggest the same edit again, simply reject it.