# Dissociate from answer after someone edits it?

Tags: support, post-disassociation

I'm still finding my way around stackexchange, having joined only a short while ago.

The User Interface is a big step up from Wikipedia's software, fresher and more contemporary.

The one thing that's bugging me has to do with editing of signed answers by other users. It's not the third-party editing that bothers me, I accept that.

What I'd like to know is, (a) is there a feature to have the system notify me via e-mail if one of my answers gets edited and (b) can I subsequently remove my signature from the answer if I don't like the edits someone else has made?

This question is not about offering forensic "proof" of who is responsible for what part of an answer, the public version history takes care of that, right? It's about the ability to step in and prevent a casual reader from getting a wrong impression.

Comment: About (b), you can *rollback* the edit if you feel it is damaging your original post.

Comment: By "signature" do you mean a real, manually written one, or your ownership of the original post?

Comment: @Goran Jovic Good of you to answer so quickly! I had looked at [the FAQ](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#editing) before asking this Q, but "rollback" isn't mentioned there.

Comment: @Pekka The latter... However, based on Goran's answer I now feel that's taken care of and only part (a) of my Q remains open.

Comment: Related: [There needs to be a way to delete content or disassociate your account from said content](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26844/there-needs-to-be-a-way-to-delete-content-or-disassociate-your-account-from-said).

Comment: Actually, you can request a disassociation from the post, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239366/could-we-have-a-help-center-page-on-disassociating-posts

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> **(a) is there a feature to have the system notify me via e-mail if one of my answers gets edited**

I do not believe that you are *e-mailed* when one of your answers are edited—the system is very reluctant to e-mail users, in part to keep down unwanted e-mail traffic, but also in an attempt to encourage people to visit the site more frequently.

But you *are* notified. As [Jeff's answer here indicates](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/120006/153008), there's a top-bar notification for edits that goes something like:

> You have {n} new edits. See your responses.

And in case you miss the top-bar notification (or it doesn't show up for whatever reason), you can see a full history of edits other people have made to yours posts in your user profile. To get there, open your profile page (by clicking your name in the top bar), select the "responses" tab, and filter by "revisions".

> **(b) can I subsequently remove my signature from the answer if I don't like the edits someone else has made**

No, unfortunately you cannot. Well, not selectively. You can always e-mail the team and ask for them to anonymize your account, removing your name from *all* the posts you have contributed, but you can't do this for individual posts.

But you don't have to resort to that because **you can always roll back edits made to your posts that you disagree with**. For example, if I wanted to roll back David's edits to [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9654193/error-in-pinvoke-signature-while-trying-to-write-mouse-click-code/9654253#9654253), I would click on the time above his name at the bottom (indicating when he was the last one to make an edit) to show [the revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/9654253/revisions):

[image]

and then click the "rollback" link on whichever revision that I want to use:

[image]

In general, users should not be editing other people's answers in such a way that they would ever *want* to "disown" those answers. Edits are largely intended to fix minor typographical errors, and sometimes used to fix relatively minor factual errors. In all of my time participating on Stack Exchange sites, I can honestly say that I've seen *at most* one edit made to one of my posts that I've strongly disagreed with, and I just rolled that one back.

Comment: That's useful, thank you. I'd upvote both your and Pekka's answer but I can't... yet :/

Comment: Edits can also add links to resources, and that is perfectly acceptable, if the resource is on topic. An edit should not add something the OP didn't say, but eventually make the post clearer.

Comment: @EugeneSeidel: You are able to vote now, also don't forget the accept mark. :)

Comment: Is the topbar notification network wide? I've never seen it before :s

Comment: I gave Cody's answer the checkmark. Pekka's answer is just as good but Cody's has the added benefit of an _in situ_ demonstration through Bo's edit :)

Comment: Now, if only there was a way to stop such ridiculous mug shots appearing next to your answer.......  ;-)

Answer (score 9):

> is there a feature to have the system notify me via e-mail if one of my answers gets edited

Nope - you will see the edit in the "responses" tab, but there is no active notification.

> can I subsequently remove my signature from the answer if I don't like the edits someone else has made?

It shouldn't happen that an edit makes you want to forfeit ownership of your answer.

In such a case, it is entirely within your rights to roll it back. If you feel an edit distorts the meaning of your post, or otherwise reduces it in value, there's no need to silently accept it.

There are exceptions to this in the case of *questions*: if you are a newbie, and a more experienced user works on your question to make it better suitable to SO's rules and culture, think twice before starting a rollback war - it *could* be that the editor knows what they're doing, and they're actually trying to help you.

But with answers, seeing as everyone can add their point of view *by simply adding another answer*, there is no need to keep an edit around. Rollback and politely point out in a comment why you didn't feel the edit  to be suitable.