# No notification was received for an edit to a post

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, edits, notifications, global-inbox

Normally, when a user edits one of my posts, I receive a notification like on the following depending on the case

1. User has editing privilege (click to visit revision)

   [image: first]
2. Users' edit is submitted to review queue (click to visit review queue)

   [image: second]

The above notifications were received instantaneously (or less than 30 minutes, in case caching is supposed to be the answer) as the edit was done/suggested.

But I did not receive any such notification today (yet) on an edit made on my [post here](//stackoverflow.com/posts/19483554/revisions). I think it is a possible bug and should be looked at. The recent notifications list I have is shown below:

[image: not. list]

Comment: What does http://stackoverflow.com/users/1190388/hjpotter92?tab=responses&sort=revisions show?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yeah. The revision history does show the edit being made.

Comment: Does a browser cache clear help here? Most likely the global inbox isn't being reloaded.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Nope. I didn't receive a notification on \@animuson editing the meta post either.

Comment: Minor edits don't get notifications. I think animuson's edit on this post is considered minor.

Comment: Note that the top one says "**Code** in your answer..." - it might not have detected any code changes in animuson's edit, therefore not notifying you of the edit.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

In order to reduce noise sent to users, [we only notify when "substantive" changes are made to their posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/278029/no-notification-when-someone-with-gold-badge-edits-my-question-or-answer/278032#278032).

There are a few rules as to how "substantive" is defined, but typically any of the following are enough to trigger a message:

- The edit to a question title is over a threshold (10 characters on most sites).
- The edit in the post body is over a threshold (10 characters on most sites; changes to non-visible text, i.e. Markdown formatting/link URLs/etc., are not considered).
- The edit in code sections is over another threshold (2 characters on most sites, no threshold on sites with syntax highlighting disabled).

The thresholds vary from site to site. Retagging only is not considered "substantive", hence will not send a notification. The number of characters changed is based on the plain text of the rendered post, not the Markdown, so things like formatting changes and link URL changes won't count towards it.

Comment: Is it possible to enable all notifications manually through some settings?

Comment: **Sklivvz:** I'm unclear on how to cast a vote on this: yes, your answer clearly explains what's happening, but no, I don't like it *(at all)*.  How to proceed? Ask a new question for a feature request to make this a user setting?

Comment: Scaling up websockets is a big issue. At the moment we have around 400,000 open websockets, typically, so what seems like a small change is effectively a pretty big amount of more load that we would be pumping there. There are other better things we can do with any extra capacity we can spare...

Comment: Really would like to receive these notifications. Now I feel like I need to recheck all my posts for bad < threshold edits.

Comment: @JasonC, it seems like that should be a pretty simple Data Explorer query to set up.  I don't have time at the moment, but something about owneruserid = (me) and owneruserid != lasteditoruserid, and you could even throw in a join to the users table and check for low reputation editors.  (If you write one, please post it as an answer here and, if you wouldn't mind, ping me!)  :)

Comment: @Fabby There is a [feature-request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270026/notification-when-a-trivial-edit-is-made-on-my-post) regarding that.