# No notification if someone edits my answer with a huge change

Tags: bug, edits, notifications

**Edit** after this question was identified as a possible duplicate of [another question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/202359/no-notification-was-received-for-an-edit-to-a-post).

Below is an example of an edit without a notification. The change was *huge* and still I did not receive a notification.

*And that's not over the threshold as answered [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/202359)?*

Here is the link of the [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/630530/367165).

Here is the edit

[image]

and here the notifications at this time

[image]

**how to reproduce:**

- Have someone edit one of your answers → Notification
- Have someone else edit that edit → No notification.

[Old stuff in the revision history](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/266941/revisions)

Comment: Ouch. One of the approvers has approved over 10000 edits... and rejected only 4. One of your mods should have a close look at what that user is doing.

Comment: In case of suggested edit, you get notification for the suggested edit itself, letting you review it. As far as I remember, no second notification in case the edit is approved by others before you have chance to review it yourself. No bug here. Since it is not clear what exactly is the edit you claim you wasn't notified about, not posting this as answer yet. (also, not sure what the last screenshot got to do with your question.)

Comment: @ShadowWizard in the last screenshot should be an edit notification. But there is no entry and I did not get a notification.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Second screen shot removed as it was a left-over from the original question. Sorry for the confusion and thanks for the heads-up. 
The edit I didn't get notified about was not an approved edit before I had time to approve it. It was a substantial edit to one of my posts' code that should clearly have crossed [the threshold for notification](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/202359/no-notification-was-received-for-an-edit-to-a-post/202415#202415) but clearly didn't, and it's reproducible...

Comment: I mean the screenshot showing actions of some user. [This one](http://i.stack.imgur.com/q2Avr.png). How is it relevant to the question?

Comment: Also, link to the actual post of yours that was edited without sending notification might help, you link to this question of yours, not sure if by mistake.

Comment: Anyway, @Fabby feel free to try and reproduce this on one of my own posts on a site where you have 2k+ rep, I don't have a problem with that

Comment: @ShadowWizard I've added the link into my question. And here: http://askubuntu.com/a/630530/367165

Comment: @A.B. wait, you mean you didn't get "An edit was suggested..." notification? Can you please double check, in your network profile inbox as well?

Comment: @ShadowWizard I've double checked this.

Comment: So this whole report is totally messed up and confusing. Correct report is "I wasn't notified of a suggested edit on my post" with link to the post, and maybe screenshot of your inbox with the "gap" where the notification should have been. That's it. Everything else is irrelevant noise, e.g. "huge change" - since suggested edits can't be minor to begin with, it's not relevant.

Comment: @Fabby after OP will edit, sure. Can't see how chat will help?

Comment: a screenshot (as @ShadowWizard mentioned) of your notification tray would be helpful. You should be able to figure out close to the exact spot where it should be :)

Comment: @ɥʇǝS There was a screenshot, taken at the same time: http://i.stack.imgur.com/q2Avr.png. Or in the revisions: http://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/266941/revisions

Comment: @A.B. That is a screenshot of actions, not notifications. Of course it wouldn't show under actions on your profile!

Comment: @ShadowWizard I have added a screenshot of the notifications.

Comment: OK, admit I do not understand what exactly is going on so guess better wait for a dev. Cheers, and good luck! :)