# Notification when a trivial edit is made on my post

Tags: feature-request, edits, notifications, global-inbox

Currently, a user does not get any notification when a trivial edit (less than 6 characters, by a user who has the [edit privilege](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit)) is made on one of his/her posts. As in [this example](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/posts/29850/revisions).

Even though the user is trust-worthy (owing to the rep of the user), wouldn't it be nice for the OP to get a notification whenever an edit is made, even trivial?

Comment: The owner of the post *does* get notified for edits to their post.

Comment: @animuson only non trivial edits. Sometimes, even 1 character is important.

Comment: @animuson  No, not when a user with the edit privilege (and/or the mod) does the edit.

Comment: @Dawny33 Who performed the edit is not at all relevant when determining whether to notify. Was it perhaps trivial as Shadow Wizard states? Very few characters changed?

Comment: @animuson guess he means the edit [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/267374/revisions). It changed only two characters, hence no notification was sent. (threshold is 6 characters, or changing code)

Comment: @animuson  Yes, [this](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/posts/29850/revisions) for example

Comment: So you mean only trivial edits, since you do get notified about "big" edits, as you were just notified about the edit I've made here now. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard  Yeah.  Received the notification :)   And yeah, even trivial edits need to be notified IMO.  Sometimes a short edit might damage /change significant content.

Comment: Agreed, already upvoted after editing.

Comment: Answer to this question seems to be related: [No notification was received for an edit to a post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/202359/no-notification-was-received-for-an-edit-to-a-post).

Comment: I agree minor update are also relevant and should receive notification. In my case a person remove one tag I consider relevant twice and I only realize when revisit my question.

Comment: Maybe some people really don't want to receive notifications after their posts were edited. It think there should a button somewhere in the preferences, which determines whether you want to receive notifications about edits or not.

Comment: Ironically the bounty message says "***An** small edit can still significantly mess up an answer.*" When it should be … **A** small edit can still… or … **Any** edit, even tiny, can still… I wonder if that error was deliberate.

Comment: @Dawny33 I wonder...Do question followers get notified of edits that are less than six characters?  If so, we definitely should.

Comment: @Dawny33 I'm currently following your post, so if you want to test it, ping/comment me ;)

Comment: @Ollie didn't get any notification for your edit :)

Answer (score 11):

I too would like to see this implemented.  A small edit *can* still mess up a post, and I would happily trade the "noise" sent to me in exchange for knowing about all the edits on my post.  [This](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/202359/no-notification-was-received-for-an-edit-to-a-post#comment686245_202415) comment asks about enabling all the notifications manually in the user settings, and I agree.  It would be nice to have the option of seeing some or all of the edits made on your posts, like with the "reduced ads" option in our preferences.

Comment: _mess up_ like changing adjectives. and words describing the degree of want, hope, emotion, one-liners that mess up advice, etc.

Answer (score 8):

In addition to Ollie's answer, I would also like this. As an example, one of my posts which included the word "color" was edited <sub>1</sub> to change the spelling of ***that one word*** into "colour". It was only changing one character, and I was notified of it by another user pinging the editor.

I would like to know of edits like these, because they are trivial and I don't like the word "color" to be spelled "colour", at least in my posts.

And sometimes one character can make a difference. For instance, a user with full editing rights could just change the d in duck to an f on a really old post with a lot of answers. Nobody would most likely notice if the author of the post wasn't notified.

Maybe we could have this as a profile setting - so some can opt out of these notifications. I know some people just hate having their inbox full, especially high rep users.

<sub>1 - This editor had full editing rights</sub>