# Shouldn't I get a notification when someone edits my question?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, edits, notifications

When someone suggests an edit I get a notification so I can approve. But it looks like if someone with enough reputation points edits my question, it doesn't send anything.

Shouldn't I get a notification? In case I don't agree with the changes, have a chance to rollback to original version.

Comment: You get, unless it's a minor/trivial edit.

Comment: Looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yaco9.png

Comment: @Shog9 not always.

Comment: Juan's does, @Shadow.

Comment: @Shog9 huh, couldn't really know what post OP here meant. So in such case probably better reopen and tag it as [tag:status-norepro]?

Comment: @ShadowWizard I dont get a notification for tag removal.

Comment: @Shog9 I got that one, but for a tag removal I didnt. I only realize when visit my question again.

Comment: So see the dupe I linked to. Retagging is considered minor edit, and indeed not generating any notification.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Yes I read, but I think is a bad practice, because removing the tag lose some target audience. And the editer did it twice. And there is not way for me to know :(

Comment: So this is a dupe of [that other request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270026/notification-when-a-trivial-edit-is-made-on-my-post). I bumped it with a bounty, not much we can do further. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Looks like you are right, but already one year and no more report there. So looks like I have to check my post for now.

Comment: True. I'm afraid only small fraction of feature requests ends up being implemented, but still better than nothing. As for your specific "problem", you can have a daily routine of checking [this page](http://movies.stackexchange.com/users/23881/juan-carlos-oropeza?tab=questions&sort=activity) - this will show you questions that have been edited on top. Best one can do at the moment.

Comment: That said, getting into edit war with a moderator is really not a smart move. Your question will just end up being locked, and you didn't even try to explain why you think the tag belongs to the question. (You can ping the moderator with comment reply i.e. @namehere on the question.)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Thanks for the link, I didnt realize was a moderator, Tought was a generic person. I leave a message now on why I think is relevant. To me was obvious `the flash` tag is relevant because that is the code show in the t-shirt

Comment: @ShadowWizard Issue was solve, wrote to moderator, I now understand I have to add more information to make the tag relevant Thanks.

Comment: Cheers, and glad it's all resolved now. :)