# Why am I not notified for edits on answers and posts?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review, edits, answers

There's a question I answered some time ago (about 2 weeks) and now I see there were some edits introduced a week ago by another person to the question and to my answer. Why am I not notified of these edits? I'd like to be because for instance if the question was changed, maybe my answer is no longer valid (I mean it doesn't answer the updated question and I can loose reputation). And if my answer was changed, maybe it doesn't answer the original question, maybe it's changed completely (at least I can't guarantee the opposite). I assume people with great reputation edit posts and answers only slightly and if there are some mistakes that can easily be fixed, but you don't need to have 10 thousands of rep to make edits, so how am I protected from people trolls or people who accidentally made my answer invalid? I feel uncomfortable with such rules and I'd like to be at least notified of changes.

Comment: If you want to be notified you need to either favorite or bookmark a post. Usually when people introduce errors in a post another person reverts these changes.

Answer (score 4):

You *are* automatically notified of [substantive changes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/202415/295232) to a post you wrote. If you're worried about a question you answered getting edited, you can always [follow it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661/295232) and you'll be notified of substantive changes (and comments and new answers) too. It would not be a good idea to make this a standard feature; some people have answered thousands of questions. Imagine the number of notifications they would get; most of them are completely irrelevant and that's a lot of noise to wade through. Edits that completely change the meaning of a post are rare and as @Luuklag says in the comments, they're usually caught (because the edit bumps the post, making it visible again for a lot of people browsing the site and/or specific tags) and rolled back.

You can use the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) to regularly check for edits on your answers or their questions. [Here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1296596/edits-to-your-answers-or-their-questions) is a first attempt for that. Please note that SEDE is updated only once a week, on Sunday morning, so this definitely doesn't work as well as real-time notifications.

Comment: Small edits can still mess up the grammar of a post. I'd want to know about these; and I don't want to follow every answer I've ever given.

Comment: @S.L.Barth-ReinstateMonica there is already a FR for that: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270026/notification-when-a-trivial-edit-is-made-on-my-post?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @Luuklag Thanks; bountied it!

Comment: Ok, now I see it's made the way it's made for convenience purposes. But I think some people would like to not have their answers or questions modified at all without a request (or for some period of time like for a week). So maybe by default people don't care about edits, but for some people it can be crucial. So I image a button somewhere in the user preferences like allow or disallow edits without a request. If the question is really badly written and people don't have permissions to edit it, the community can downvote that question or answer (maybe a bit radically, I'm just proposing)