# Why do I get notifications if one of my questions is edited?

Tags: support, edits, notifications

It's been some months since the last time I was around on the community so I'm still *updating*.

Today I got a notification that one of my questions was edited, I checked it, everything was fine and I wanted to **accept** it but didn't find the button, so I assumed a **moderator** did it. I then checked the question's page and realized that my question was edited by a normal **user** *(with a lot of rep but still a **user**)*.

Is there something new regarding this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not new. You get a notification every time somebody else *tries* to edit your post [substantially](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/202415/21960), or if it is indeed edited substantially because the user has enough reputation (usually 2000) to get his/her edits approved automatically. It doesn't matter if the user is a ♦ moderator or not.