# Edits to question titles don't seem to be sending an inbox notification to the author anymore

Tags: support, edits, notifications

This morning, [one of my posts was edited](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/363719/revisions) but I wasn't notified. It's 51 characters so I think it's [substantive enough](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/135961/295232) (I've received notifications for smaller edits), so I was wondering whether it was caused by the fact that it only added a link (so the plain text of the post is identical) and I was intending to post a feature request that such edits should be considered substantive as well.

However, from some science on sandbox posts, <s>it seems notifications aren't generated *at all*</s>. The last one I got was for [this edit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/348075/revisions) which happened yesterday.

[image]

---

**Update:** It seems to be by design that the edit mentioned above didn't raise a notification, as Makyen commented that it only changed a link, which doesn't affect the plain text of the rendered post. Further testing confirmed that notifications *were* being sent for substantive text changes.

However, after posting this question, its title was edited twice, but **I didn't receive notifications for either of those title edits**. According to [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/202415/377214), users should be notified of title edits to their posts, and the two edits in question were definitely substantive enough. This doesn't seem to have been working for a while; is it an intentional change or a bug?

Comment: FWIW, I didn't get a notification from Sonic's edit to this question either.

Comment: And neither did I get a notification from your edit to [my answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox/363737#363737).

Comment: Not getting a notice for [the edit this post is about](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/363719/revisions) is [tag:status-bydesign]. Changes to Markdown, including changes to links/URLs, etc. are not considered in the number of characters which are changed. Thus, overall, the change this is about is not above the threshold for notification. The same applies to the test answer edit which @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog mentions (also adds a link/URL). OTOH, I thought edits to titles did generate a notification.

Comment: It seems @Makyen is right. I was just notified of your second text edit to my answer.

Comment: The fact that Markdown doesn't count is explicitly mentioned somewhere, but I'm not easily finding the Meta post where I read it. I first encountered this when I was disturbed by not getting notifications of quite substantial URL changes for some of my answers in the process of decommissioning SE Documentation. I recall having to go through all of my posts looking for any where the most recent editor wasn't myself. At the time, I did find something which provided a better explanation and did state that Markdown changes were not counted. IIRC, it was that the changes have to be to visible text.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog I didn't get a notification from your latest edit.

Comment: @Makyen OK, then I'll make a separate feature request for the case where a link is added. I think that's important enough to be notified about.

Comment: @Makyen I've checked [a few cases for title-only edits on my questions](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/1401598/title-only-edits-by-somebody-else-than-the-post-author) but couldn't find a notification. So maybe they never generated notifications at all?

Comment: @Glorfindel Then maybe the title needs to be changed and not include “anymore”, or maybe you should specify that in the body.

Comment: @EkadhSingh that makes sense, but I'm not 100% convinced they never did, and also I'm still wondering why my sandbox tests this morning (using substantive body edits) didn't generate notifications. So I'll have to experiment a bit more I guess ...

Comment: @Glorfindel yeah, if you’re still not sure after testing maybe add something like “I think this is a recent change, but I’m not sure.”

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation; added in an update from what we've seen. Feel free to modify/remove.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog this is perfect, thanks a lot!