# How can I follow my own post?

Tags: support, follow-post

I posted a security-related answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68050132/4518341) on Stack Overflow, and I'd like to know if someone edits **any part of it**, not just the code. How can I do that? Is it even possible?

I looked at both pages of the [original announcement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661/343832), but didn't see a solution. The most relevant thing was [Franck Dernoncourt's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/345706/343832), which seems to imply that it's not possible to get notifications for every edit:

> [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)
>
> Add the ability to unfollow one's own question or answer.

Comment: [Related(?), duplicate(?)](//google.com/search?q=site%3Ameta.stackexchange.com+notification+tag+edits) to / of [Notify on retagging](/q/168675/289905). I think tag edits and title edits are the two parts that you don’t get a notification for. This applies both to followed posts and own posts.

Comment: @Sebastian I'm not sure what you mean. My post is an answer, so it doesn't have tags or a title.

Comment: Ah, okay, but then you should always get a notification anyway.

Comment: @Sebastian I've never gotten a notification for non-code edits to my posts. Is that a new thing?

Comment: You get notifications for [substantive edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/135961/295232); it doesn't matter if it's your own post or if you're following it.

Comment: @Glorfindel Thanks! That led me to [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/202415/343832) which answers my question well enough for me!