# Are answerers notified when a question they've answered is edited?

Tags: support, questions, notifications

Does The System currently notify all those who have answered a question when that question is edited or updated?

Or do we manually have to come back and check to make sure our answer is still relevant to a question that may have morphed or [become a chameleon?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions)

Comment: I think that it should notify you when your question is changed!  Especially since your name is still prominently displayed on the post...

Comment: @kan: Way to not read.

Comment: Duplicate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2322/notify-us-when-the-question-has-been-edited-after-posting-an-answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, the question will be noted as edited. You can click on that edited date and see the revisions.

Only comments or answers to your question will be notified to you (the question OP). Every answerer will only be notified of comments to their individual answer.

Answer (score 3):

No, it does not notify.