# Will people who have answered my question automatically be notified of updates to the question?

Tags: support, questions, edits, asking-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does StackOverflow currently notify all those who have answered a question when that question is edited?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28586/does-stackoverflow-currently-notify-all-those-who-have-answered-a-question-when)

As the question states - Will people who have answered my question automatically be notified of updates to the question? Or do I need to inform the user that I have made an update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, they will not be updated automatically, unless they have favorited the question (selected the star).

If you want to notify them you will need to comment to them specifically.

Comment: How do I comment to them specifically?

Comment: Um. Just like you did here. You comment on their answer. I got notified that you did.

Comment: I think you got notified because I commented on your answer. However if I want to notify someone who has made a comment I think I have to mention their @Name in my comment