# Show rep lost or gained from rescinded votes

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, reputation, reputation-summary

My rep on SO just changed from 14,546 to 14,558.

Checking my recent activity, I saw that I'd received one upvote which only accounts for 10 of the 12 points.

Obviously someone has rescinded a downvote on one of my posts - but which one?

While it's trivial in this case, it's more serious if you lose an upvote as you'll lose 10 points, but not know which post it is. It would be useful to know, so that you can double check to see if there's anything missing or wrong in the post. For example, it could be that a question has been edited which now makes your answer misleading at best or just plain wrong at worst.

The same has been asked [when you lose the accepted answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25351/notification-when-my-answer-is-unaccepted).

Comment: You care too much about rep. Go to ineedprofessionalhelp.stackexchange.com

Comment: @John - not really, it just happened to notice the change this time ;)
Though a valid reason is to be able to correct answers that may be wrong now due to changes in the question or new versions of software etc.

Comment: Maybe we can revive this feature request: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2322/notify-us-when-the-question-has-been-edited-after-posting-an-answer

Comment: I'm still jonesing for a global rep recalc so we can tell the hordes coming in wondering where their rep went to... <fill in unsavoury metaphor of your choice here>

Comment: @Eth: The Great Rep Recalc and 1000 other Myths - Read our fairy tales on Meta...

Comment: It could just be a mobile device and someone with very fat fingers.

Comment: @Ladybug Killer: Ever notice the people that say "rep's not important" are the people with the most of it?

Comment: @John: That's probably why they say it. But we are talking about SO rep here. So take a look at my SO account, before you make anchorless statements.

Comment: @Ladybug Killer: I can't find an SO account named "Ladybug Killer"...

Comment: @John: Hint: Same user ID like Meta.

Comment: @Ladybug Killer: I found it but my point is still the same.  You said what you said, and on this site at least, you have a lot of rep.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is now [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) given the recent changes that are being made to keep the display reputation in line with *actual* reputation, as outlined by Nick Craver here:

[Recent Reputation History Changes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123319/upcoming-reputation-history-changes)

Answer (score 1):

I think this is something you'll need to write an app, against our API, to accomplish -- or support this feature in an existing app that is under development.

http://stackapps.com

Comment: Why would something like this have to be implemented out-of-band? Apart from the obvious time constraints I'm sure the SO team works under, there shouldn't be any technical challenge to implement this in the SO engine? After all, you are registering that a vote is removed...

Comment: how is this possible using the API?  `/users/{id}/reputation` doesn't list the action when sorted by most recent.  It's as if the vote or acceptance never existed in the first place.  If that's the case it seems like the only possible way would be to take a snapshot of a users entire reputation history and perform a "diff" when something like this happens.  That's pretty unfeasible given that theres a limit of 100 records per API call, although I could have overlooked something.

Comment: I keep coming back to this issue. It is quite annoying when one looses a rep, not because of loosing points mind you. But loosing a vote usually indicates that there is something wrong with the answer, or there's been a change in the question which invalidates the answer. Thus I would like to update my answer. But I cannot! Because SO doesn't show me the answer that needs updating! IMO if SO indicated what answer/question lost a vote, this may lead to improved content, which is what we want isn't it?