# Track undos that affect rep change

Tags: feature-request, reputation, recent-activity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Show rep lost or gained from rescinded votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40519/show-rep-lost-or-gained-from-rescinded-votes)

I just visited SO and noticed my reputation had gone up by 2 points.  Since I haven't accepted any answers for a while I can only assume that today someone removed a down vote they cast my way some time ago.  I'm actually really curious as to which of my 925 answers that might be but, *darn it all*, I've gone and forgotten which ones I had down votes on.

Obviously vote undos and accepted answer undos don't actually log a change in reputation, they just delete the action from before.  This can be pretty annoying, especially in the case of users reversing acceptance of your answer.  I think it would be better if the previous action stayed on record, and the undo counted as a new action and the score change showed up on the recent activity page as well as the rep audit.

An accepted answer undo, a down vote undo and an up vote undo might look something like this:

[image: "Where are my legs?" is a tribute to bobince.]

Comment: firebug FTW! ;)