# Notify when an Answer is Un-accepted

Tags: feature-request, answers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Notification when my answer is unaccepted?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25351/notification-when-my-answer-is-unaccepted)

I was wondering if it were possible to be notified of an answer (your own) that has been unaccepted, so that one can possibly re-look at the answer and try to improve it (or perhaps learn a new way of doing something).

Comment: One way to know this is to keep a copy of one's rep audit then, when you see your rep drop by 15, generate a new audit and spot the difference.  Not ideal!

Comment: See also [Show rep lost or gained from rescinded votes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/40519/59303)

Comment: @Chris - Judging from the answers there (and the time passed since then and added functionality etc.), I don't find that to have been an exact duplicate. It's more about rep recalcs and rep history - could be my point of view.

Answer (score 3):

If you find a way, then mark this answer unaccepted for me so that I can go back and try to answer again.

Comment: And while you're at it cancel the upvotes on this comment.