# Why did I just lose 15 reputation?

Tags: support, reputation

What can cause a loss of 15 reputation?

Comment: Can you please elaborate on this. Do you want to know why you lost 15 rep or do you want to now when you have lost 15 rep?

Comment: No question mark, no hand-drawn circles, only six words...this doesn't qualify as question, sorry.

Comment: yes i want to know when i lost 15 point

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can lose 15 rep when someone who has previously accepted your answer removes the accept.  This will result in your reputation score decreasing by 15.

You won't see this in your activity though.  The only way you would know is if you kept a list of all your accepted answers and then reconciled them manually.

EDIT:

In response to a comment to this answer, I am adding these links in for reference. Although related they don't seem to imply whether this sort of functionality is being currently being implemented or not.

- [Show rep lost or gained from rescinded votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40519/show-rep-lost-or-gained-from-rescinded-votes)
- [Notification when my answer is unaccepted?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25351/notification-when-my-answer-is-unaccepted)

Comment: This is possible to unchecked the answer(Unaccept the answer).

Comment: @Isha - Yes it is.

Comment: @Barry thanx, and its ishu not isha.

Comment: @Ishu - apologies, a typo on my part :)

Comment: @Barry no problem bro.

Comment: The point about not seeing it in activity is an annoying one, IMO. I think there's a feature request for it somewhere...

Comment: isn't there a time limit on the unaccepting?

Comment: @Jon - I completely agree. I have never understood why it doesn't appear.  It would at least give you an opportunity to see which other answer was accepted and improve your answer.

Comment: @Andy, no, there is no time limit. A new, better, answer can be posted *any* time.

Comment: @Jon - I can find these two posts regarding this but they don't imply that anything is being done about it. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40519/show-rep-lost-or-gained-from-rescinded-votes & http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25351/notification-when-my-answer-is-unaccepted

Comment: It might be worth editing those links into your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can lose 15 rep when somebody unchecked an accepted answer. This is not shown in your graph. It can also be withdrawal of votes or a rep recalc. Both are not shown in any graph.

But you can be sure that if you lost those points without any trace, you does not had them before. (The rep number can be changed due to deleted questions. You can check https://stackoverflow.com/reputation to see your actual rep and its source.)

Answer (score 0):

Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/users/483888?tab=reputation) help?

Comment: Do not forget about the raw-data at http://meta.stackoverflow.com/reputation .

Comment: it is to see repotation chart and point whatever you earn but my 15 point detected without any indication.

Comment: @Ishu, I'm sorry, but you are very hard to understand :(

Comment: @Ishu - look at the 'related' question here in the right hand column