# Negative reputation but no activity

Tags: feature-request, bug, status-bydesign, reputation

I checked my SO account this morning to find that I had -15 rep for the day. I find this rather odd since I haven't been down voted or have any bounties out. It *looks* like one of my accepted answers got unaccepted but I don't seem to have any visibility into that? Is there a way to track down this phantom negative reputation?

Comment: If you lose an accepted answer you are not notified of this and cannot track this within SE (see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1659/please-show-us-when-we-lose-an-accepted-answer , http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25351/notification-when-my-answer-is-unaccepted and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72207/why-did-i-just-lose-15-reputation for example), this seems the most likely cause.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you like to monitor which answers got unaccepted,

save https://stackoverflow.com/reputation page everyday to your local computer,

and try diffing those when you see, you losing something.

Comment: @andrew-white this happened to me recently, when an asker initially accepted my answer, but then switched their accept-checkmark to someone else's answer.