# Un recorded rep change

Tags: support, reputation

On StackOverflow my rep just went up to 418 from 403. I went to another page and it was 403 again, but my profile states "There were no net reputation changes on this day".

I have "show removed posts" ticked, and cannot see any changes at all in my questions/activity etc.

If the same person up votes and downvotes my same answer, does this just reset rep and not show either activity (up/down)? (this is all I can think of)

Cheers

Comment: By the difference of reputation I would guess that one of your answer has been un-accepted. This does not show up in the activity if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: If the change happens in a short period of time (I think the same day) nothing gets recorded. (eg post gets accepted than unaccepted)

Comment: ok ta. Not miffed, just wondered. suppose "no rep change for today" is accurate as a summary, but strictly speaking there was rep change. Not the end of the world, cheers.

Comment: @James If you want a way to see the reputation change maybe this could help you http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86593/negative-reputation-but-no-activity

Comment: @Marc-Andre it will show up in the reputation ([see an example](http://i.stack.imgur.com/dm3M2.png)) unless it happened in a very short time (in which case the accept/unaccept merely cancel each other out).

Comment: @AaronBertrand Thanks for the information, I wasn't sure.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Given the 15 rep difference, one of your answers was most likely accepted for a brief moment, and unaccepted soon after. This will not result in an actual event in your rep history, other than the "no net changes" message.

Comment: In this case, it was [this answer of his](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/18517678/timeline) that was accepted briefly then unaccepted.