# I don't know why my reputation decreased

Tags: support, reputation

I don't understand why my reputation decreased from 256 to 241.

I even checked on [my reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/reputation) but it is not showing what I believe to be the correct result.

What might be the problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The difference is 15 points.

It looks like someone changed their accepted answer from yours to another answer.

See also [Show rep lost or gained from rescinded votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40519/show-rep-lost-or-gained-from-rescinded-votes) and [Notification when my answer is unaccepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25351/notification-when-my-answer-is-unaccepted)

Comment: is it??? then its ok otherwise i was thinking there may be some bug..

Comment: Specifically, it looks like [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4645791/how-to-programmatically-get-imei-number-in-j2me/4645940#4645940) used to be accepted, and the asker switched to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4645791/how-to-programmatically-get-imei-number-in-j2me/4646292#4646292) 9 hours ago