# Why is my reputation not appearing for this month?

Tags: support, reputation

This month, I have earned 16 points. Until yesterday, my reputation score was correct, but I just logged into my Stack Overflow account and now it is showing -1 reputation for this month.

Is this a bug? What might be the problem?

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/users/300517/chandan-shetty-sp?tab=reputation#reppage_1-repview_time

Comment: Its showing correct points(+16 for this month)... But it is not added to total points.

Comment: @Chandan What does http://stackoverflow.com/reputation say for "total rep" at the bottom?

Comment: What? Your reputation score will be the same as that shown in the reputation breakdown. If you've lost a point, then you probably downvoted someone else's answer. Downvotes on answers cost you 1 point.

Comment: Yesterday it was 1198... But today it is showing 1183. I didn't see any negative points in the reputation breakdown list.

Comment: Likely someone removed "Accepted Answer" from one of your questions...

Comment: Is it possible to know which answer is removed from "Accepted answer"...

Comment: possible duplicate of [I don't know why my reputation decreased](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79282/i-dont-know-why-my-reputation-decreased)

Comment: It happend me for the first time... So i just wanted to know the reason... Thanks david for the answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Likely someone removed "Accepted Answer" from one of your questions...  *– davidsleeps*
>
> Is it possible to know which answer is removed from "Accepted answer"... *– Chandan Shetty SP*

Yes, if you lost 15 points (why weren't those detailed numbers there in your original question?), then davidsleeps is *exactly* right about what happened. One of your previously accepted answers was *unaccepted* by the person who originally asked the question.

That is perfectly acceptable behavior, of course, but you don't ([at least currently](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1659/please-show-us-when-we-lose-an-accepted-answer)) get a notification when it happens. The only way to find out is to go through your answers (displayed in your profile) one-at-a-time and see which one used to be accepted but isn't anymore. It's a fairly tedious, painstaking process for minimal gain. The best option is really just to learn to live with a little bit of rep fluctuation.

And as otherwise suggested in the comments, in the future you can audit your own reputation using the spiffy graphical [reputation history](https://stackoverflow.com/users/300517/chandan-shetty-sp?tab=reputation#reppage_1-repview_time) available in your user profile, and/or the text-based audit accessible at the `/reputation` page: https://stackoverflow.com/reputation

Comment: Then its fine... It happend me for the first time... So i just wanted to know the reason...