# Is there a way to track accepted answers that have been un-accepted?

Tags: support, reputation-audit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Notification when my answer is unaccepted?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25351/notification-when-my-answer-is-unaccepted)

Today I lost 5 reputation despite someone upvoting one of my old answers. So I suspect that someone else that had accepted an answer of mine have un-accepted it. Out of curiosity, is there any way to track this?

Comment: Go to http://stackoverflow.com/reputation and save it, diff that later on.

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40519/show-rep-lost-or-gained-from-rescinded-votes

Answer (score 2):

There is not an easy way to track this other than saving information about your accepted answers and manually comparing it later.  YOU's idea of using the /reputation page is most likely your best bet.

There are other ways to lose rep that are hard to track as well:  Up-votes that are removed, user's deleted or questions deleted.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Looking my reputation page I've discovered that two days ago I reached 205 of reputation and now it's 190. So I've lost one day of reputation cap. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you remember the question, you can check the "unaccepted" status on question timeline

For example, https://stackoverflow.com/posts/5780298/timeline

[image]

Comment: So it could actually be reported then?

Comment: @ChrisF, technically, I think they can, but I am not sure they want to alert users with that status change, because we cannot do anything with OP's unaccepting our answers.