# Reputation lost. Log for reputation loses?

Tags: support, reputation, lost-reputation

I had 134 reputation points, then suddenly the number changed to 129.

I have seen some Lost Reputation questions, but I'm still confused:

1. Is there a way to recover lost reputation?
2. Is there a reputation log where I can see transparently what's going on with all my points?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Show rep lost or gained from rescinded votes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40519/show-rep-lost-or-gained-from-rescinded-votes)

Comment: @ChrisF that's more of a feature request and this is more a support question, definitely related though

Comment: @Daniel - fair enough.

Comment: @ChrisF I dont see the relation. My question is far more simple. Take a look to the acepted answer to see what I was looking for. I just didnt know that "You can audit your reputation from the reputation page."

Comment: That's why 5 close votes are needed - in case someone gets it wrong. However, in this case you're still not going to see where you lost those 5 points if someone removed a question up-vote.

Comment: [What does it matter, in the end?](http://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet?tab=reputation)

Comment: Some of us are less than 300k behind. We will catch up soon!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Some one might have revoked an upvote against your question. You can audit your reputation from the [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/reputation) page.

Comment: thx, I have check it and I don`t see anything strange... if an upvote has been revoked it should appear something like -5, no?

Comment: @AMGG - from my memory - it won't come like that. Only downvotes / bounty should show a explicit negative rep in the report.

Comment: @AMGG - No, votes that are revoked are just gone. One explanation is: I use a touch device and scroll by moving a finger along the edge. Occasionally I hit the voting arrow by mistake and quickly touch it again to revoke the vote. If you happened to check at exactly that moment, you would see the wrong rep before it is corrected.