# What happened to my rep? I lost 5 points... OMG!

Tags: feature-request, reputation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reputation lost. Log for reputation loses?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93517/reputation-lost-log-for-reputation-loses)

Because I haven't hit six figures with my rep yet, if I notice any movement when I first log in for the day I will check out which of my answers or questions got voted up.

Until today.

I lost 5 rep points. Ouch. This is obviously a lost vote on one of my questions.

But then I notice something interesting... the loss of rep is not shown in the Activity dropdown:

[image]

Nor is it shown in the Reputation page:

[image]

The lack of any information leads to me to conclude that this must be the result of a rep recalc, specifically an upvote cancellation or a user being deleted. So my question is:

***Can we have a clue as to what caused the drop in rep?***

I'm looking for something as simple as an entry inserted in the Activity window with a short explanation.. *Down vote*, *Reversed upvote*, *Question deleted*, *User deleted*, etc.

This is not a big issue for me and I'll still be able to sleep if nothing ever comes of this, I am just eternally curious so I like to know *what* or *how* something happened.*

*<sub>Not knowing something like this has the effect of changing my [Minkowski](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_space) perception of spacetime back to [Euclidian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_space) with an abnormal bump in it. Y'know what I mean? There's a wrinkle in my spacetime continuum that needs to be smoothed out.</sub>

Comment: It's the tax...

Comment: It always cracks me up when 10k+ rep users make a big deal and raise an issue on MSO about single-digit rep changes.

Comment: I think you spelled ZOMG wrong :)

Comment: @Mark - if one of my applications does something unexpected, I need to track it down and know specifically what caused the issue, I can't just write it off as a side effect of a living breathing complex system. The same goes for SO - **how** it happened is more important and relevant than **what** happened. SO is not inhabited by ordinary hoomans who will just ignore or not even notice this sort of thing :)

Comment: +1 for the footnote. Normally questions about rep loss bore me; I chuckled at this one.