# Lost 15 reputation points, but where? (which accepted answer? or are there other options?)

Tags: discussion, reputation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Please show us when we lose an accepted answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1659/please-show-us-when-we-lose-an-accepted-answer)

If i hover over my name, i can see that my reputation has lost -15 points today. I am assuming that either

- an answer of mine that was accepted is now no longer accepted, and the OP selected another answer. How can I see this?
- the answer was completely removed?

Is there a way to tell where I lost the reputation? If i check `stackoverflow.com/reputation` it actually show 15 points less than is shown at stackoverflow itself.

Comment: Related - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40519/show-rep-lost-or-gained-from-rescinded-votes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely this one,

https://stackoverflow.com/posts/6222451/timeline

probably because he want more or better answers on his bounty.

[Rails Generator: generate files based on already existing rails files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6222451/rails-generator-generate-files-based-on-already-existing-rails-files)

Comment: Awesome! Is there a link on the site to go to the timeline of a post/question? Or is it hidden. Anyways: very useful, thank you very much.

Comment: @nathanvda, there is two browser script at stackapps.com, [SE Modifications](http://stackapps.com/questions/2138) and another one called Hidden Links by me.

Comment: Wow, very nice. A whole new world opens to me: stackapps.com! Great scripts. Thanks!