# Can we not see the the reputation which is been given and taken?

Tags: support, reputation, reputation-summary

I got 15 reputation and 10 reputation by acceptance and upvote respectively, then these sum ob reputation had been fetched from me. How can i see the log what had happened, during this process.

---

Edit:
Actually my real problem is that I had 1386+ reputation yesterday when I closed my window, but now there is 1377

---

Edit:
Now I have 1359 rep and I have no record of why, as the history is only showing +2 reputation.

Comment: Yeah it's about taking back..

Comment: Do you mean the votes were undone, and you want to see those? If so, that's currently unavailable - basically the system acts as if those votes never happened.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: But later, the were giving 10 reputation and taking back only 2, in case of vote back

Comment: Related Links: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40519/show-rep-lost-or-gained-from-rescinded-votes and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25351/notification-when-my-answer-is-unaccepted.

Comment: Time for a manual rep recalc?

Comment: @rptwshti: Sorry, it's really not clear what you mean to be honest... Have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/reputation?

Comment: Here's the big link, upvote this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1659/please-show-us-when-we-lose-an-accepted-answer

Comment: Please don't abuse us with your big bold text, or I shall have to wither you with scorn and derision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reputation comes and goes sometimes. Recalculations occur once in a while to make the count more accurate, because it's quite a complex system and during the day some factors of it are "best guess". That's why you might see it waver from time to time.

There are also some nightly anti-abuse mechanisms that can undo votes if odd voting patterns are detected. I'm not accusing you of abuse, but it does demonstrate once again that reputation can waver slightly without you necessarily expecting it.

More obviously, people may unaccept your answer, or change their vote on one of your questions/answers. This information would just "disappear" from your reputation history so it wouldn't be evident to you that it had occurred unless you constantly performed a full diff on your entire reputation history.

Answer (score 1):

Go to your profile, then click on the "reputation" tab at the top of the page. You'll see a listing of events that caused loss and gain of reputation.

[image]

Comment: It's not showing all the events that took place, seems as this feature have been removed..

Comment: @rptwsthi: Don't forget that your SO and your meta.SO profiles are distinct.

Comment: I remember that these are distinct.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Due to the recent changes that are being made to keep the display reputation in line with *actual* reputation, you will now have a more accurate display of the changes in your reputation.

This is outlined by Nick Craver here:

[Recent Reputation History Changes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123319/upcoming-reputation-history-changes)