# How do I get notified if an answer to my question changes?

Tags: support, notifications

There's a similar post about this [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2322/notify-us-when-the-question-has-been-edited-after-posting-an-answer).
Recently when I was just checking [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17059662/what-is-the-equivalent-of-visual-studio-command-window-in-netbeans) of mine I noticed that the answer had changed. Had I not visited my question by accident I'd never know about this.
Is there a way that I can get notified when an answer to my question changes?
Checking the response tab in my profile only shows 1 answer to my question (i.e does not reflect the edit).

Comment: You can periodically [look at your own question list and just sort by activity](http://stackoverflow.com/users/279982/atomerz?tab=questions&sort=activity)  That will indicate questions with recent edits to answers.

Comment: @Servy That's good to know, but wouldn't it be nice if I'd just get notified like a new answer?

Comment: Most edits are not material to the answer.  When they are, the poster will often post a "see my edit" comment.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Can't disagree with that :)

Comment: No, this is not possible. What you can do is favorite your own questions, then any changes, including edits to answers, will highlight the "favorites" tab in your profile. No notifications, but better than nothing.