# Can I be notified of edits to answers on questions I own?

Tags: feature-request, comments, edits, notifications

I asked a question ([Applying space formatting in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1463800/applying-space-formatting-in-visual-studio)) and got several answers pretty quickly. I tried them and they didn't work. So I left some comments on the answers looking for clarification, and apparently the posters edited their answers – but I wasn't notified. I forgot I hadn't found the answer to my question and just came back to it today wondering why there wasn't any activity, only to find out that I'd been ignoring it.

**Note**: I didn't find a question on Meta that addresses my issue, I'm sure it exists, though. So, if it does, kindly let me know.

Comment: It's not a dupe, that's about notifying a user about his own answers being edited.  I'm asking about being notified when someone else's answer to my question has been edited.

Comment: to clarify, it's not a dupe of that question, it may well be a dupe of another question.

Comment: Very close to this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2303/notify-us-when-an-answer-weve-accepted-has-been-edited