# Add notification for when a followed question accepts an answer and when a followed answer gets accepted

Tags: feature-request, notifications, accepted-answer, follow-post, unaccepted-answer

I follow the questions that I answer, and oftentimes I would check back at the question I answered most recently to see if their OP accepted an answer. If so, I would be able to review the accepted answer to gain a better understanding of the problem *(and maybe improve my answer and/or edit the question to be more clear, if necessary)*.

Can we get a notification when a question we followed accepts an answer, and when an answer we followed gets accepted?

I suppose the same should go for un-accepting answers, if this were to be implemented.

Comment: Does this answer your question? I think it's very closely related. [Notify us when an answer we've accepted has been edited](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2303/notify-us-when-an-answer-weve-accepted-has-been-edited)

Comment: @RoryAlsop Thanks, but it doesn't. The thing is, I provide many answers on Stack Overflow, but rarely ask questions. Also, in the linked post, we can simply follow the answer we accepted.

Comment: Agreed with Ann here (as a note to fellow reviewers/voters) - this is a request to notify when there is an accepted answer to a followed question - this and the old FR are *separate* types of notifications.

Answer (score -1):

For me this would be unnecessary noise. If this gets implemented, then please only as optional feature and not as default behaviour for followed posts.

I follow posts when I'm interested in the topic. It is nice to get notifications about new answers/comments/edits so I can check if I can learn something about the topic. A random OP accepting an answer is nothing that would be interesting for me.

Comment: Totally agree. Just more needless noise. You can check in profile activity to see if a question you answered has an accepted answer or not also

Comment: @charlietfl Yes, but due to a recent change in many Stack Exchange communities *(including Stack Overflow)*, the accepted answer is no longer pinned to the top, making it harder to locate.

Comment: I don't think it's much noise. Unless the author is abusing accepts, it's extremely rare for accept notifications to cause a lot of clutter: most authors just accept one answer and move on. Also, if the solution changes due to later updates, many would like to be notified. Finally, if the author is indeed abusing accepts, this would trigger the user notified to flag for moderator attention and thus more likely a mod will stop the abuse.

Comment: When I follow a question, I expect to receive some noise notifications. Getting notified for every comment is more burdensome than being notified for an accept. I agree that it would be nice to have more control over what you receive, but making the interface more complicated requires developer work and probably makes the feature less usable and useful for unsophisticated users.